# Writing multiple variables to a text file on seperate lines in python

Tags: python

i have  5 variables and i want to write them all to a text file using 1 line of code rather than repeating the x.write() function 5 times. Im really not sure how to do this please help

Comment: Take a look at the Python [writelines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("{}{}{}{}{}\n".format(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5))

vars = (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join([str(i) for i in vars]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3.6 or newer, you can use [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) F-strings, to do it concisely

```
with open("path/to/file", "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{var1}{var2}{var3}{var4}{var5}")
```